# restrict the scope of variables in a mysql query? with brackets?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't remember what the method is meant to be for ensuring the scope of a variable in a query is restricted to prevent mysql injection.

where should i put brackets in the following examples?

```
UPDATE table SET col_1 = '$var', col_2 = '$var2' WHERE col_1 = '$var3'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE WHERE col_1 >= '$var1'
```

(Obviously looking for answers not using PDO!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent SQL injection, use a [prepared statement](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/356.cfm), the MySQL equivalent of a parameterized query.

Example:

```
$db_connection = new mysqli("myserver", "user", "pass", "db");
$statement = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT thing FROM stuff WHERE id = ?");
$statement->bind_param("i", $id);
$statement->execute();
```

And yes, that means *do* use PDO

Comment: ah ok, i must have been mistaken. I thought there was a method for manually parametizing my vars ( equiv of bind_param("i", $id) )

Comment: @Haroldo: Well, I've seen `%d` string format statements being done, but they are a weak hack. Prepared statements and PDO are the *only* way. You're going to have to learn to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Brackets have nothing to do with scope and scope has nothing to do with preventing SQL injection.

If you are restricted from using PDO and mysqli, you can prevent injection by escaping your data with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET col_1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($var)."'";
```

Comment: Use a prepared statement, *not* any `escape_string` variant

Comment: And if prepared statements are unavailable to him? That's what my question addresses.

Comment: @webbiedave - When would PDO ever be not available?

Comment: Scope does have to do with SQL injection, especially with register_globals.

Comment: prepared statements and PDO have been around for more than 5 years. The odds of neither being available are very low.

Comment: @Coronatus, Randolpho: I'm on a project now where PDO is unavailable to me. @Marcus Adams: My point was that just because a variable is not global doesn't mean it's immune to injection.

Comment: @webbiedave: you are using PHP4 and are unable to get the owners to upgrade? Push for the upgrade, man.

Comment: @Randolpho: I have and succeeded. But they won't do it for 6 months. It's the best I could do lol!

Comment: @Marcus Adams - register_what?

Answer (score 0):

Brackets have absolutely nothing to do with preventing SQL injections.

I could give you an answer using `mysql_*()` functions, but I won't.

If you want to be a programmer, you have to learn best practices. Saying "Obviously looking for answers not using PDO!" is ridiculous and you have a terrible attitude to go for the simple route.

Comment: Thank you Coronatus, however from my research in this instance PDO would not be appropriate, i specifically put 'not PDO answers' because there are PLENTY of PDO discussions already on stackoverflow!

Comment: @Haroldo: PDO is very appropriate! Why would it *not* be?

Comment: I did lots of reading about it here on SO yesterday and go the impression that id you weren't reusing the obect PDO was not advised. are there any instances when PDO should not be used then?

Comment: No. Always use PDO. It will make your code more secure (actually, you will never need to worry about SQL injection again), more OO, and just look more "good" :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as scope affecting SQL injection, I think you're talking about the PHP [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals), setting. Ensure it's off.

Register globals basically allows a user to create a global variable simply by passing in a parameter to a GET or POST. So, if you're using a global variable in your SQL access, and the user can guess your variable, they can inject code by setting the value.

Brackets have nothing to do with scope in PHP, however.

Take a look at the following to avoid SQL injection:

- Server side validation
- PHP filters
- SQL Escaping
- Parametrized Queries

You should be doing all four.